# Serial Port Driver-Got stuck in SerialISR () routine

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port, driver

I am writing windows device driver first time for multiport serial pci card.May be this one is stupid question but i got stuck.Need someone's help.Let me first explain what I have done yet.I have bus driver which creates number of child (2/4/8/16) depends on card. Now I have to write function driver for it.The bus driver creates interrupt which I have to use.Now in my driver I got bus interface,interrupt created in bus driver and related information.I am using [Serial Port Driver Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Serial-73a4564d/file/42753/40/Serial%20Port%20Driver.zip) for reference.Now in `SerialISR ()` routine my driver got stuck in while loop.

```
  ServicedAnInterrupt = TRUE;
        do {

            InterruptIdReg &= (~SERIAL_IIR_FIFOS_ENABLED);
            switch (InterruptIdReg) {

                case SERIAL_IIR_RLS: {

                    READ_LINE_STATUS(Extension, Extension->Controller);

                    break;

                }

                case SERIAL_IIR_RDA:
                case SERIAL_IIR_CTI: {

                    READ_RECEIVE_BUFFER(Extension, Extension->Controller);

                    break;

                }

            case SERIAL_IIR_THR: {

                    //
                    // Alread clear from reading the iir.
                    //
                    // We want to keep close track of whether
                    // the holding register is empty.
                    //

                    Extension->HoldingEmpty = TRUE;
                    break;

                }

                case SERIAL_IIR_MS: {

                    READ_MODEM_STATUS(Extension, Extension->Controller);
                    break;

                }

                default: {

                    ASSERT(FALSE);
                    break;

                }

            }

        } while (!((InterruptIdReg =
                    READ_INTERRUPT_ID_REG(Extension, Extension->Controller))
                    & SERIAL_IIR_NO_INTERRUPT_PENDING));
```

Every time it goes into  `case SERIAL_IIR_MS`. This process continue for some time about 1 min & then test pc will crash.What can be the reason behind that & what should I do to overcome this problem?I have gone through [msdn library information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Also read issues regarding this on OSR website.

Comment: It has been some time since I've worked with drivers, but I believe that you need to clear the interrupt bit flag in the register, once you have processed it.

Comment: @kgiannakakis, thanks for the replay and I did it but it was not useful.